# Validação automática de inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validação

Estou criando uma área de login e me veio uma dúvida: desejo saber se existe uma forma de verificar no meu banco de dados se o e-mail digitado no campo de cadastro já está em uso em meu site, porém quero que isso seja feito automaticamente (após o cliente digitar o login no input uma div do lado imprimir se já existe ou não, existe uma forma de fazer esses tipos de validação automáticas sem o uso de um submit ?

Comment: Crie um serviço em Rest que busca validar o email enquanto faz o preenchimento do registo.

Comment: Não faz sentido isso ser no login, não seria no cadastro?

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você vai precisar usar ajax e preferencialmente jQuery:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // A cada tecla precionada executo o AJAX
    $("#id_do_campo_de_texto_onde_sera_inserido_o_email").keydown(function () {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "pagina_que_fara_a_busca_no_banco.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {email: $("#id_do_campo_de_texto_onde_sera_inserido_o_email").val()}
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
           // data = será o retorno da página "pagina_que_fara_a_busca_no_banco.php"
           if(data == 1){
               // existe
           }else{
               // não existe
           }
        });

        request.fail(function () {
            console.log("OPS... ocorreu um erro na requisição");
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP: pagina_que_fara_a_busca_no_banco.php**

```
<?php

//coloque seu select aqui e verifique se o email existe

$sql = "SELECT... WHERE campo_email_banco like %".$_POST['email']."%"    
$email = "execute aqui a query";

if($email != ""){
    echo "1";
}else{
    echo "2";
}

?>
```

No arquivo PHP você utiliza o método de pesquisa que preferir, como eu acho muito pessoal não escrevi o código certinho (eu por exemplo utilizo classe)... Mas o importante é entender a lógica.

Comment: Sim entendi perfeitamente, da para implementar um beforesend com uma gif durante as requisições certo ? Pois pensei em executar a requisição só apos ser colocado o caractere @ pois e meio desnecessário tantas requisições, enquanto esse caractere não for colocado a gif fica rodando até que seja colocado ou até que o input perca o foco.

Comment: @EstudantePHP nesse caso é melhor quando o campo perde o foco, com o @ fica muito vago, podem existir guilherme@gmail e guilherme@hotmail ambos validos mas não repetidos.

Comment: verdade então minha logica ali não funcionaria :(

Comment: porem o ideal me parece tentar fazer a requisição depois de um tempo que o usuário parar de digitar